# What sizes should be the images when loading from some CDN for Android

Tags: image, imageview, cdn, pixel

I'm creating an app for Android and I should load images from a CDN and I want to support all the possible screen sizes. How should be done?

Should be many different versions of the same image stored in the CDN in different folders? Or one only resolution can cover all the screen sizes if it has high resolution?

Also How I know the exact numberXnumber? how I can know that? I should try manually or there are guidelines?

For example if that helps I have an ImageView 100dpX100dp how I know how much should be the pixels?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set up essentially the basic ranges that android uses, mdpi, hdpi, hdpi-x, hdpi-xx.  So you would have low and medium resolution screens request cdn.com/mdpi/image.png, high resolution request cdn.com/hdpi/image.png and so on...  You define the resolutions within each grouping, for example on hdpi-xx Your images may be 1920x1080, but on hdpi it is only 1280x720.  Those are just examples pulled out of the air, but you can adjust to suit your needs.

You can even use the base android resource system to pull the correct url for each screensize.

i.e.

In the folder values-mdpi you put a string resource that will have the url with mdpi, and hdpi with the base url for hdpi, you get the idea.

For further information you the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) provides very clear examples and more detail.

Comment: So that means if I have an ImageView 100dp X 100dp in mdpi screen this is 100px X 100px right? so the cdn.com/mdpi/image.png the image should be 100px if I ask for cdn.com/hdpi/image.png this should be 150px X 150px because the ratio is 1.5 right? But What happen with images that are wrap_content and they don't have static size?

Comment: It is a little more varied depending on screen density, but more or less. You should try experimenting if you can at different screen resolutions to see how your application performs vs. how big your images are.